# Combining three Worksheet_Change subs

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine three Worksheet_Change subs.

I have a spreadsheet that has data validation. I want an input box to appear depending on what is selected.

Column "I" has data validation, with the options of Accepted, Declined and Null in Void.
If "Accepted" then nothing.
If either Declined or Null in Void, I would like a pop up box to appear for the user to input $0, and paste that to Column "D".

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Declined" Then
            roww = Target.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(roww, "D").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Updated quoted value to 0", Type:=2)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Null in Void" Then
            roww = Target.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(roww, "D").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Updated quoted value to 0", Type:=2)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Column "M" has data validation, with options blank and Complete.
If blank then nothing.
If Complete, I would like a pop up for the user to input the Quotation value, and paste that to Column "D".

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Complete" Then
            roww = Target.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(roww, "D").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Updated quoted value to the Quotation Value", Type:=2)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Complete" Then
            roww = Target.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
            Cells(roww, "D").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Updated quoted value To the Quotation Value", Type:=2)
            Application.EnableEvents = TRUE
        End If
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Declined" Then
            roww = Target.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
            Cells(roww, "D").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Updated quoted value To 0", Type:=2)
            Application.EnableEvents = TRUE
        ElseIf Target = "Null in Void" Then
            roww = Target.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
            Cells(roww, "D").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Updated quoted value To 0", Type:=2)
            Application.EnableEvents = TRUE
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

see [this official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement).

Comment: It worked!!!
Thank you NavyLover